# Why BSON is not using uint32_t instead of int32_t for document lenght

Tags: c, mongodb, bson

According to BSON specification an int32_t is used for the total number of bytes comprising the document.

I can also see that mongo-c-driver is using Libbson and it's using int32_t.

But what is the reason to use **signed** integer instead of **unsigned** integer?

the document size will never be below 0. Can someone please explain the reason?

Comment: Why is this tagged C? In C, one sometimes uses signed types for values that can never be negative because it allows writing loops like `for (int32_t index = end; 0 <= index; --index)` where we only process (execute the loop body) values of `index` that are non-negative, but the termination test requires that `index` be negative. But that does not need to be part of the document format specification. The type used in the format does not need to be the type used in code to process it, although some programmers will unthinkingly adopt the specified types for their code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil because Libbson is a C library and the same for mongo-c-driver. It still does not give sense to define the prefixed lenght as int32_t in the BSON protocol. If we look deep how Libbson handle the BSON, there is no such loop needed, but the int is still signed.

Comment: In the format there is a distinguish between signed and unsigned integer as it happens to be part of the supported types for BSON which leads me to believe it not random. As example you would not use int32_t for UTF8 as you may lose some high bits.

Comment: I suspect the reason is to ensure an entire document can be loaded into a 32-bit address space.  While a large `int32_t` value *may* be too large to fit in some 32-bit address spaces, if `uint32_t` or larger were used there definitely would be documents too large to fit into 32-bit address spaces.  The next smaller widely-available sizes - `uint16_t` and `int16_t` - would almost certainly be deemed too small.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good point! - Yes that a very valid reason. But the only issue i got with this statement is that int64_t, uint64_t and decimal128 is also supported types in BSON, if uint32_t is too large than they also are surely too large - –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document size is limited to 16 MB, which fits in a signed 32-bit integer with room to spare.

While document size limits larger than 16 MB *were* considered, my guess is there was no serious consideration of document sizes exceeding 2 GB, therefore the difference in range afforded by using unsigned 32-bit integers for length wasn't a meaningful benefit.

Thus, there is no reason to use an unsigned type.

Reasons to NOT use an unsigned type:

- Wraparound potential from UINT_MAX to 0.
- -1 could be used as a special designator.

Comment: All good reasons. But with signed 32-bit integer you get undefined behavior. With unsigned 32-bit integer you are not limited to 16 MB, but can still if wanted limit the document to 16 MB or more.

Comment: What undefined behavior?

Comment: Unsigned integers is guaranteed to wrap around on overflow, but signed integer overflow ends with undefined behavior.

Comment: There are many ways you can get in trouble with integer operations. The fact that signed overflow is undefined doesn't mean it's worse than working with unsigned types.

Comment: Exactly - int32_t or uint32_t is not bulletproof solution to avoid any issues. The protocol should define the rules. -1 as a special designator logic can be replaced as it reminds me of PostgreSQL that still can't handle null byte while other db's can with lenght prefix. I hoped that there was more bigger reason from BSON for not using unsigned int.

Comment: If you decide to implement your own database you can do whatever you want, but how is that relevant to the question you asked?

Comment: I was addressing some of your point in the answer like 'wraparound potential', that both integer types can end bad if not limited by a protocol like BSON that is used in the mongo-c-driver DB ( the subject ). I don't think that why they choose signed 32-bit integer.  For the special designator, you can limit one or more of 4294967295 range for that if needed to replace -1. I was just sharing some of my conclusions, but maybe the reason is that there is no real reason

Comment: The fact that you would have implemented this differently has no bearing on how MongoDB behaves (or why it does the way it does) which was your question.

Comment: Correct, i seek the answer to my question - The reason behind the decision of choose still feels unjustified. I admit that you are maybe closest to the reality. I accept your answer